# How to add script code using javascript?

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I want to add script tag using javascript, but I am not able to get it work. Below is code. I want to add this code in bigcommerce cart page.

```
    var duration = document.getElementsByName("cartdata");
    var cartstr = '<!-- MyBuys Page Parameters – Place in <body> element -->';
    cartstr += '<script type="text/javascript">';
    cartstr += 'mybuys.setPageType("SHOPPING_CART");';
    cartstr += 'mybuys.set("email","consumer@example.com"); <!--consumer email can be blank if not known-->';
    cartstr += 'mybuys.set("amount","99.34");';

    for (var i = 0; i < duration.length; i++) {
        str = duration[i].value;
        var n = str.split('|');
        cartstr += 'mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("'+n[0]+'","'+n[1]+'","'+n[2]+'");'+'<br>';
    }

    cartstr += '</script>';
    cartstr += '<!-- End MyBuys Page Parameters -->';

    //alert(cartstr);

    var script   = document.createElement("script");
    script.type  = "text/javascript";
    script.text  = cartstr;           // use this for inline script
    document.body.appendChild(script);
```

I want below code added to page:

```
<!-- MyBuys Page Parameters – Place in <body> element -->
<script type="text/javascript">
mybuys.setPageType("SHOPPING_CART");
mybuys.set("email","consumer@example.com"); <!--consumer email can be blank if not known-->
mybuys.set("amount","99.34");
mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("12345","1","54.34");
mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("56789","3","45.00");
</script>
<!-- End MyBuys Page Parameters -->
```

Comment: Why in the world would you append a script, just call it. There is no need to build the string!

Comment: It could be a sensible task if the JavaScript source is the optional return of e.g. an AJAX call.

Comment: @MichaelBesteck So you're using PHP to generate JavaScript to generate more JavaScript? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates how to dynamically add JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var optionalFunctionLoaded = false;
        var commonFunction = function() {
            console.log("test button clicked " + (new Date()).toLocaleString());
            if (!optionalFunctionLoaded) {
                // get optionalSrc e.g. via AJAX, eventually providing actual input values
                var optionalSrc = 'function optFun(){console.log("optional function");}';
                // if optionalSrc is not empty 
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.innerHTML = optionalSrc;
                document.head.appendChild(script);
                optionalFunctionLoaded = true;
            }
            if(optionalFunctionLoaded) optFun();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id ="testButton">test</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("testButton").onclick = commonFunction;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tested with Firefox 24.0 / Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just add the code to the page:

```
<!-- MyBuys Page Parameters – Place in <body> element -->
<script type="text/javascript">
mybuys.setPageType("SHOPPING_CART");
mybuys.set("email","consumer@example.com"); <!--consumer email can be blank if not known-->
mybuys.set("amount","99.34");
mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("12345","1","54.34");
mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("56789","3","45.00");
</script>
<!-- End MyBuys Page Parameters -->
```

Why use JavaScript to put it there? Just add it to the page. You might have to adjust it a bit with your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < duration.length; i++) {
    str = duration[i].value;
    var n = str.split('|');
    mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal(n[0],n[1],n[2]);
}
```

Comment: mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("12345","1","54.34");mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal("56789","3","45.00"); values coming dynamically that is why I need to embed it in script code.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be executing the code, there is no need to build the string. In the end, what you are trying to do is the same thing as running the code! Just execute it.

```
mybuys.setPageType("SHOPPING_CART");
mybuys.set("email","consumer@example.com");
mybuys.set("amount","99.34");

for (var i = 0; i < duration.length; i++) {
    str = duration[i].value;
    var n = str.split('|');
    mybuys.addCartItemQtySubtotal(n[0],n[1],n[2]);
}
```

Comment: Actually I need to integrate this code in bigcommerce, in one template I am getting all values and in second template I need to put values in script code, so it generate whole script code...

Comment: It does not make sense that JS is generating a string which will be executed a few lines later.

Comment: I have put the code as you have said. Just want to confirm that its 3rd party script and will not create any issue if we add our own code in it? right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you want to do that. But if you really want to, here is a way you could try.

`$('body').append("console.log('blah');")`

OR

`$('body').html($('body').html()+"console.log('blah');")`

*Replace console.log('blah') with your code*

Note this is assuming you are using **JQuery.**

If not, you can still use Native Javascript to do something similar. Just search for creating an element and adding it to another using vanila javascript and you'll get lots of information on google.

Although, as *epascarello* says, its not a good idea to do this. Its basically a code smell and you can improve your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using javascript.